# Displaying the nested foreach with if else in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement, foreach, nested

**Controller**

```
public function admin()
{
    // get the current date employee logged in details
    $data['get_attendance'] = $this->attendance_model->get_attendance();

    // get the active employee details
    $data['get_employee'] = $this->attendance_model->get_employee();

    //print_r($data['get_employee']); exit();

    // attendance page
    $data['header'] = "Employee";
    $data['sub_header'] = "Attendance employee";
    $data['main_content'] = 'attendance/admin_list';
    $this->load->view('employeelayout/main',$data);
}
```

**Model**

```
public function get_attendance()
{
    return $this->db->where('date',date('Y-m-d'))->get('attendance')->result_array();
}

public function get_employee()
{
    return $this->db->where('is_active',1)->get('employee')->result_array();
}
```

**Views**

```
<?php $count = 1 ?>
<?php foreach ($get_employee as $employee) { ?>
<tr class="gradeX">
    <td><?php echo $count++ ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $employee['first_name'] . ' ' . $employee['last_name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $employee['employee_number'] ?></td>
       <?php foreach ($get_attendance as $attendance) : ?>
        <!-- if employee exists -->
           <?php if($employee['employee_id'] == $attendance['employee_id'] ) { ?>
            <td><?php echo date('M-Dj-Y',strtotime($attendance['date'])) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $attendance['mark_in_time'] ?></td>
               <td>mark out going</td>
               <td>Active</td> 
            <?php  break; ?>

       <?php } elseif($employee['employee_id'] != $attendance['employee_id'] ) { ?>
           <td><?php echo "i'm absent" ?></td>
           <?php  break; ?>
      <?php  } ?>
       <?php endforeach; ?> 
    </tr> 

    <?php } ?>
```

I want to display the currently logged in (present) employee and display the absent employees too. I'm getting the employee details from employee table.
and attendance details from attendance table. if an employee is absent and I want to display the absent else display the login details. where here foreach loop not displaying properly with if condition. what's wrong with the loop.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php foreach ($get_employee as $employee) : ?>
    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td><?php echo $count++ ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $employee['first_name'] . ' ' . $employee['last_name'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $employee['employee_number'] ?></td>
           <?php foreach ($get_attendance as $attendance) : ?>
            <!-- if employee exists -->
             <?php if($employee['employee_id'] == $attendance['employee_id']) : ?>
                <td><?php echo date('M-Dj-Y',strtotime($attendance['date'])) ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $attendance['mark_in_time'] ?></td>
                   <td>mark out going</td>
                   <td>Active</td>

             <?php elseif ($employee['employee_id'] != $attendance['employee_id']) : ?>
               <td><?php echo "i'm absent" ?></td>

             <?php else : ?>

             <?php endif; ?>

          <?php endforeach; ?> 
    </tr> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Apply left join in place of two different queries.**

Because currently you have applied two loops and their comparisons, will consume a lot of execution time And I don't think this is the good code If you get thousands of data than definitely you can analyse the execution time.

So it's better to apply join query.